# Different types of function throwing error in typescript

Tags: typescript

Why is the return type of `c` function `void`? Does typescript control flow analysis do this? or is this because of javascript?

```
let a = () => {
    throw new Error("A");
} // never

let b = function() {
    throw new Error("B");
} // never

function c() {
    throw new Error("C");
} // void
```

Comment: I suppose in the last case TypeScript infers that you don't return anything at all and assumes it should be `void`

Comment: I think the better explanation is that it doesn't matter. You can return `void` or `never`, both of which compile just fine

Comment: @Anatoly Yes, but what about first two cases? I am not explicitly returning anything, but typescript assumes that their return types are `never`.

Comment: @Anatoly the other two also don't return anything. The control flow is the same in all three cases - `a`, `b`, and `c` will always throw an error, so `never` is the appropriate result.

Comment: @Mike S. The thing is that `never` is subtype of all types, this means that you can always "return" `never` type even if function return type is different, but not vice versa.

Comment: @VLAZ Yes. Duplicate.